# Service `http` get method doesn't return success or error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am writing a service that returns array of cars. My service method dont return sucess or error. The folder `assets` is in the same directory as `app folder.

This is my service method:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Car} from '../../../domain/car';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class CarService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
    getCarsMedium(): Promise<Car[]> {
       console.log("call1");
       return this.http.get('assets/data/cars-medium.json')
       .toPromise()
       .then(res => {
          console.log("sucess1" + res);
          console.log("sucess2" + res.json());
          return res.json().data as Car[]
          })
       .catch(error => {
          console.log("error");
          console.error(error);
       });
   }
```

}

I call it as:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Car} from "../../../domain/car";
import {CarService} from "./car.service";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './car.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car.component.css']
})

export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
  cars: Car[];

  constructor(private carService: CarService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("call2");
    this.carService.getCarsMedium().then(function (cars) {
      cars => this.cars = cars;
      console.log(cars)
    });
  }
}
```

This is how my `json` looks like:

```
{"data":[
    {"vin":"a1653d4d","year":1998, "brand":"VW","color":"White"},
    {"vin":"a1653d4w","year":1999, "brand":"VV","color":"White"}
]}
```

Entity class:

```
export interface Car {
  vin?;
  year?;
  brand?;
  color?;
}
```

EDIT:
getCarsMedium() dont return sucess or error.
console output: 
    call2
    call1

Comment: I don't see how it could return undefined. It returns a promise. Which could be resolved or rejected. What happens when you enter `http://localhost:4200/assets/data/cars-medium.json` in the browser location bar and hit enter (assuming you're using the CLI, here, otherwise change the port to the actual one)?

Comment: Returns my cars json

Comment: OK, so what happens precisely? Add some console.log() in your code, post it, and tell us what the output is.

Comment: What happens if you return `res.json()` instead of `res.json().data`?

Comment: I add two console.log here:
`getCarsMedium(): Promise<Car[]> {
    return this.http
      .get('assets/data/cars-medium.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data as Car[], res => console.log(res));
  }`
and here:
`ngOnInit() {
    this.carService.getCarsMedium().then(cars => this.cars = cars, cars => console.log(cars));
  }`

Console displays nothing

Comment: @FrankModica console still  displays nothing when i return res.json()

Comment: Your `res => console.log(res)` is being passed as the 2nd function to `.then`, which means it only executes during errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason: I have jwt-authentication in project
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial][1] - it blocked my request

Answer (score 1):

```
return this.http.get('assets/data/cars-medium.json') 
    .toPromise() 
    .then(res => res.json().data as Car[], 
          res => console.log(res));
```

Obviously, that won't print anything, since you're printing  the response from a second callback passed to then(), which is executed in case the promise is rejected (which it is not).

Do that instead:

```
return this.http.get('assets/data/cars-medium.json') 
    .toPromise() 
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.json());
        return res.json().data as Car[]
    });
```

Comment: I change, but still get empty console:(

Comment: That's why I suggested to add several console.logs. Put one before the call to http, for example. My guess is that you just never call your service. Your debugger would also help.

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    console.log("call2");
    this.carService.getCarsMedium().then(function (cars) {
      cars => this.cars = cars;
      console.log(cars)
    });
  }` 
`getCarsMedium(): Promise<Car[]> {
    console.log("call1");
    return this.http.get('assets/data/cars-medium.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.json());
        return res.json().data as Car[]
      });
  }`
Console output: `call2 call1`

Comment: Just edit question. Output in console is: "call2 call1"

Comment: OK. Now add a console.log in the success callback, and add an error callback where you also have a console.log. Make them all distinct.

Comment: I edit question and add this two console.log .
Output is still the same

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, despite using basically the same code as what you posted. The problem must be elsewhere. Try replicating it in a plunkr, just like I did: http://plnkr.co/edit/T0mBUAU0ddOTKAPAPy5D?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for help. You really helped me. I found the reason - I have jwt-authentication in project.

Comment: That is still quite strange. The JWT authentication should normally just return a 401 error if the token is not there, and thus your error callback should execute.

Comment: i thought the same way, but when I removed it everything began to work